# Communication between iPhone and Internet over a web service

Tags: .net, iphone, web-services, communication

From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290924/iphone-interaction-with-asp-net-webservice/1503206#1503206), @Pravara asked a question in answer.

The question is something like this.

> Is the XML is only way to communicate between .Net web service and iPhone? I have implemented it, in my application, but I am facing performance issue, as the time required to scan each tag of XML takes time.
>
> Please can anybody suggest any way for communication other than sending XML in response.

I would like to know the same.

(I know web service means itself XML, But I found it very typical, like transfer entire database to XML while creating web service & again parse it by iPhone - is a laborious job.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is a better communication protocol because of it's small size and ease of integration in my opinion.  You'll want to check out [JSON.framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/), [TouchJSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON), and [ObjectiveResource](http://github.com/yfactorial/objectiveresource/tree/master)

Comment: Better is, of course, subjective. JSON is great for the reasons you've specified, but it is terribly painful to use if you have data structured in deep hierarchies. It's a lot easier to query an XML document with XPath in those cases compared to the cascade a dictionary within a dictionary within a dictionary, etc... type structure you get when you convert a JSON string using one of the libraries you've linked. I'm all for JSON and said libraries, but sometimes XML is in fact "better".

Comment: well said, everything has benefits and drawbacks

Answer (score 2):

[Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/) is an even better communication protocol than JSON. Being a binary format it is even more compact, and with a strict format parsing is much faster.

As a bonus there are already frameworks for Java, .NET and PHP to expose a web service. Truly easy. Asume you have this C# interface:

```
public interface ITest {
  public string getGreeting();
  int addNumbers(int a, int b);
}
```

Then implementing it on the server using [HessianC#](http://www.hessiancsharp.org/) is a snap:

```
public class CTest:CHessianHandler, ITest {
  public string getGreeting() { return "Hello World!"; }
  public int addNumbers(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
  [STAThread]
  private static void Main(string[] args) {
    CWebServer web = new CWebServer(5667, "/test/test.hessian", typeof (CTest));
    web.Paranoid = true;
    web.AcceptClient("[\\d\\s]");
    web.Run();
    for (;; ) {
      if (Console.ReadLine() != "") {
        web.Stop();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On the iPhone side the C# interface need to be translated into an Objective-C protocol:

```
@protocol ITest
-(NSString*)getGreeting;
-(int)addNumbers:(int)a :(int)b;
@end
```

And then using [HessianKit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hessiankit/) for getting a proxy for the service is almost as easy:

```
id<ITest> proxy = [CWHessianConnection proxyWithURL:serviceURL
                                           protocol:@protocol(ITest)];
NSLog(@"Greeting: %@", [proxy getGreeting]);
NSLog(@"The answer: %d", [proxy addNumbers:40 :2]);
```

In this short answer the method names are not quite C#-ish, an not quite Obj-C-ish either. This is because by default HessianKit uses Java's naming conventions. This can be overriden in HessianKit by providing method, and type name translations. So that both the C# and the Obj-C sides on the connection feels 100% at home. For example:

```
[CWHessianArchiver setClassName:@"com.mycompany.ITest" 
                    forProtocol:@protocol(CWTest)];
[CWHessianArchiver setMethodName:@"AddNumbers"
                     forSelector:@selector(addInt:toInt:)];
```