# How to write a server for an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, http

I'm writing a very simple iPhone app, basically a dropbox where people can submit ideas and then view what's in the dropbox. I need to write a server that will respond to my iPhone's (HTTP?) requests. Are there any good tutorials on the web that will show me how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well it really depends on what kind of platform are you trying to write your server. 
If it's going to be linux, apache, mysql and PHP (LAPM) then probably this question would answer some of your questions: [Serving a json file for IPHONE app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742749/serving-a-json-file-for-iphone-app)
Also this one might be helpful: http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:Creating_JSON_Data_in_PHP

You could server your data in various formats: binary, XML, JSON, etc. However if I were you i would definitely choose JSON ...

You also can use ruby, .net or anything else for building your web server, however probably php is going to be the one with the most examples.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For communicating with the server take a look at ASIHttpRequest, which has some good documentation and example code included http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Answer (score 0):

i recomment using the ASIHttpRequest Classes.

On the serverside just use a simple JSON API and probably oAuth or HTTP Authentication to submit and receive Data from a Database.