# How to decleare custom protocol in iPhone

Tags: iphone, hessian

I want to use a protocol, how can we implement it in iPhone.

> ///In POCViewController.h
>
> #import
>
> @protocol BasicAPI
>   -(NSString*)hello;
>   @end
>   @interface HessianPOCViewController : UIViewController 
>   {
>    idbasicAPI;
>
> }
>
> @end

///

> // In POCViewController.m
>   // In Some method
>
> NSURL* url = [NSURL
>   URLWithString@"http://www.caucho.com/hessian/test/basic"];
>
> id proxy =
>   (id)[CWHessianConnection
>   proxyWithURL:url 
>   protocol:@protocol(basicAPI)];
>
> NSLog(@"hello: %@", [proxy hello]);
>
> ////

Please help me how I can implement above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above code snippet - the @protocol block goes in your header file, underneath the @end declaration that's already there. Common use case is something like:

```
@interface MyClass
// properties, method definitions, etc
@end

@protocol BasicAPI

-(NSString*)hello;

@end
```

Then in some method body in your implementation file, MyClass.m

```
-(void)myMethod { 
   NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString@"http://www.caucho.com/hessian/test/basic"];
   id proxy = (id)[CWHessianConnection proxyWithURL:url protocol:@protocol(basicAPI)];
   NSLog(@"hello: %@", [proxy hello]);
}
```

Comment: Its not working geeting error: "Can not find protocol declaration for BasicApi"

Comment: @iPhoneDev check your capitalization (BasicApi vs. BasicAPI) (and make sure you're including the .h file)

Comment: opsss sorry my bad... the change is "BasicApi" to "BasicAPI" Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I see that the example you give is taken from the documentation for the [Hessian Objective-C implementation](http://wiki.caucho.com/Hessian_-_Objective-C_2.0_Implementation). It's showing you how to interact with a Hessian web service from an Objective-C client.

Do you have an existing Hessian web service that you're trying to talk to? If so, you need to declare in your `@protocol` block the interface to that service. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290924/iphone-interaction-with-asp-net-webservice) give some good examples of how this works on both the client & server side.