# Getting Data From .net Web Service on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, web-services, xml-parsing

I have one .Net web service and I use it for mobile apps. I used it on windows phone and android apps but I didn't get data from it on iOS yet. For example, there is one method in my web service and it takes one parameter. How can I get data from returning value ? I found one example on internet and I edited it but I can't get data. All of code is here. In this case **I need a sample code**. Thanks for attention.

**web service's information**:

namespace : http://tempuri.org
url : http://www.example.com/webservice1.asmx
method name : FirmaGetir
parameter name: firID (string)

**Web service request:**

```
    POST /webservice1.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <FirmaGetir xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <firID>string</firID>
    </FirmaGetir>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

**Returning data**:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <FirmaGetirResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <FirmaGetirResult>
        <Firma>
          <firma_adi>string</firma_adi>
          <adres>string</adres>
          <telefon>string</telefon>
          <id>string</id>
          <sektor>string</sektor>
          <alt_sektor>string</alt_sektor>
          <alt_sektor_adi>string</alt_sektor_adi>
          <servis>string</servis>
          <map>string</map>
          <slogan>string</slogan>
          <sayfaGosterimi>int</sayfaGosterimi>
          <gpsilce>string</gpsilce>
          <gpssemt>string</gpssemt>
          <gpspk>string</gpspk>
          <duyuru>
            <baslik>string</baslik>
            <icerik>string</icerik>
            <link>string</link>
            <image>string</image>
          </duyuru>
          <firma_link>
            <tam_adi>string</tam_adi>
            <kisa_adi>string</kisa_adi>
            <firma_link>string</firma_link>
          </firma_link>
        </Firma>
      </FirmaGetirResult>
    </FirmaGetirResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

**SOAPExampleViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SOAPExampleViewController : UIViewController 
{
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser;
    NSMutableData *webData;
    NSMutableString *soapResults;
    BOOL recordResults;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *webData;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSXMLParser *xmlParser;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *soapResults;

-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender;

@end
```

**SOAPExampleViewController.m**

```
#import "SOAPExampleViewController.h"

@implementation SOAPExampleViewController
@synthesize xmlParser, webData, soapResults;


-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender
{
    NSString *firid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"800"];
    recordResults = NO;
    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"POST /webservice1.asmx HTTP/1.1\n"
                         "Host: example.com\n"
                         "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8\n"
                         "Content-Length: length\n"

                         "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\n"
                         "<soap12:Body>\n"
                         "<FirmaGetir xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                         "<firID>%@</firID>\n"
                         "</FirmaGetir>\n"
                         "</soap12:Body>\n"
                         "</soap12:Envelope>\n",firid];
    NSLog(@"%@", soapMessage);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/webservice1.asmx?op=FirmaGetir"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/FirmaGetir" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if(theConnection)
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is null");
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response
{
    [webData setLength:0];
     NSHTTPURLResponse * httpResponse;
    httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
    NSLog(@"HTTP error %zd", (ssize_t) httpResponse.statusCode);
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
    //NSLog(@"webdata: %@", data);
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"error with the connection");
    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received bytes %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"xml %@",theXML);
    [theXML release];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Respose Data :%@",responseString) ;
    if(xmlParser)
    {
        [xmlParser release];
    }
    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    [xmlParser parse];
    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"firma_adi"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"Firma"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"adres"] ) //I'm trying
    {
            if(!soapResults)
        {
            soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        }
        recordResults = YES;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if(recordResults)
    {
        [soapResults appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"firma_adi"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"Firma"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"adres"] ) // I'm trying
    {
        recordResults = NO;
        NSLog(@"%@", soapResults);
        [soapResults release];
        soapResults = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your url is redirecting to some other page.Give actual url.

Comment: Are you sure this works for you in anyway because you forgot to add **<NSXMLParserDelegate>** to your .h file for xml parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying solve this issue about one week. I don't search anymore about it. The best way for consuming web service is using WCF services with JSON. I found an excellent example about of it. Please follow this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/405189/How-to-access-SQL-database-from-an-iPhone-app-Via

Answer (score 3):

Replace the line below

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/webservice1.asmx"];
```

by this one.

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/webservice1.asmx/ServisKontrol"];
```

It will help.

Answer (score 2):

or just try a great free tool that generates you all the classes and proxy u need.
wsdl2code.com

Answer (score 1):

Change `http://tempuri.org/FirmaGetir` with `http://tempuri.org/ServisKontrol` in SOAPAction.
Also you can refer this link for more information. [iPhone interaction with ASP.NET WebService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290924/iphone-interaction-with-asp-net-webservice)

Comment: sorry it's my fault. I change my code, but still I can't get data.

Comment: There are some problem in your soap message also, please refer my link