# UIPickerView foreground

Tags: checkbox, uibutton, uipickerview, foreground, edges

I have a problem with UIPickerView.
I have 9 lists and I created a view with 9 buttons. For each button I have associated a flag: when I click a button, a picker appears with the list relating to selected tag.

The problem is that when the picker appears, it's in the background and the buttons are seen above the picker. I have solved in this way: when the user clicks a button the others are set as hidden and the picker looks good.

There is a better solution to have the picker in the foreground directly?

One can also change the color of the edges of pickerview and place a check box without using long code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but i understood that you have a UIPickerView and many datasources, what is the problem there exactly?

Comment: I have changed the formulation question...if you want I add the executable code.

Comment: check my response and let me know if i understood corectly

Answer (score 1):

You can bring the picker view above using `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:pickerview];` and it will bring the picker view above the buttons, or you can go in the `.xib` file or `storyboard` and make sure the picker view is the last item added in the view.

Comment: You are right: I have gone in storyboard and I placed the picker view as the last item added in the view. Thanks again.

Comment: As for the color on the edges and check box of the picker is there any quick solution?

Comment: you can set the pickerView.layer.borderWidth = 2; and pickerView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor; and you need to import QuartzCore.framework; if this is what you mean.

Comment: Great, let me know if you have any other issues.