# How to call a webservice from an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, web-services

I want to call a .net web service from an iPhone application. Like I want to call a web service with respect to name and display the history sent by the web service.

Can anyone help me with the tutorial or some code how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked a lot of times here in SO, do a search, here is a link to one [iPhone interaction with ASP.NET WebService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290924/iphone-interaction-with-asp-net-webservice)
and another [How to Fetch Data From a WebService in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289192/how-to-fetch-data-from-a-webservice-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

I use [www.sudzc.com](http://www.sudzc.com) to consume a .NET web service in a native iPhone app.